# use conditional inside style inside render

Tags: reactjs

I have this render and I have notification.isError in props, but I don't know how to use conditional to print a value inside background value, to get different colors accord to the property is Error.

I get "Unexpected token"

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '4px 10px 1px 10px',
        fontSize: '16px',
        backgroundColor: {return (this.props.notification.isError?'red':'black')},
      }}
      >
```

I've tried this too:

```
const bgcolor = (this.props.notification.isError?'red':'black');
return (
  <div style={{ padding: '4px 10px 1px 10px',
    backgroundColor: {bgcolor},
  }}
```

but backgroundColor is not showed on the browser; it's like react don't like the way to send the value

Comment: Both of your examples will work if you just get rid of the return statement and the curly braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
render() {
        return (
          <div style={{ padding: '4px 10px 1px 10px',
            fontSize: '16px',
            backgroundColor: (this.props.notification.isError?'red':'black')
          }}
          >
```